# Get selected Item ListBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I tried to get the item selected from ListBox and add it on RichEditBox, and I add the action SelectionChanged on ListBox.

```
private void RecognizedListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //gte the selected item from listbox
        string inputTextWritePad = RecognizedListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
        //add the item to RichEditBox
        MyTextNote.Document.Selection.Text += inputTextWritePad + " ";
        //clear the canvas 
        recognizerShared.ClearInk(InkCanvas);
        //return the listbox to vide
        RecognizedListBox.ItemsSource = null;
    }
```

But when I slect the item, the problem is get me the NullReferenceException an d show me this message.

> Message = "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\r\n   at WritePad_CSharpSample.MainPage.RecognizedListBox_SelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)\r\n   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsControl.put_I...

Comment: Debug your code and check the `RecognizedListBox` listbox

Comment: You get this exception just as you run your program, then when *InitializeComponent()* is fired and layout set up, the mentioned event is fired the first time and *SelectedItem* is *null*. The easiest fix would be just to check at the beggining of your event: `if (RecognizedListBox.SelectedItem == null) return;` or something similar.

Comment: I did it, but with RecognizedListBox.SelectedItem!=null and nothing happen, it doesn't add the item to the RichEditBox, also with RecognizedListBox.SelectedItem==null

Comment: @Amin Do you still get exception? Have you debuged what happens when you select an item from RecognizedListBox?

Comment: @Romasz no exception, and can't add the item to the text, this is the code //gte the selected item from listbox
            string inputTextWritePad = RecognizedListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            //add the item to RichEditBox
            if (RecognizedListBox.SelectedItem==null)
            {
                break;
            }
            MyTextNote.Document.Selection.Text += inputTextWritePad + " ";
            //clear the canvas 
            recognizerShared.ClearInk(InkCanvas);
            //return the listbox to vide
            RecognizedListBox.ItemsSource = null;

Comment: I am not sure if the original object RecognizedListBox is already updated when the event is triggered. I would have used the "sender" object and casted it to a ListBox variable to work on it. Furthermore, the Event argument "e" contains the SelectedItem and SelectedIndex already. I cannot see at which line you have the Null reference exception, but I would work with "e" instead of the global object reference.